# Is there a WordPress plugin that will tweet when a scheduled post is posted?

Tags: webapp-rec

I know there are tons of Twitter/WordPress plugins out there, but so far I have not been able to get one to do what I need.

I have lots of scheduled posts. When a scheduled post goes like, I would like a Tweet to go out announcing it. There seem to be lots of plugins that will tweet when you publish a post, but so far none of the ones I have tried will do it on a scheduled post. Right now, I am using [Twitter Publisher](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-publisher/), which does not do what I want.

Anyone using something that works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a plugin to do that. Here are 2 alternate methods:

### FriendFeed

You can use FriendFeed ([details here](http://www.crossbrowser.net/290/using-friendfeed-to-automatically-twitter-your-new-blog-posts/), disclaimer it's my blog).

### FeedBurner

If you use FeedBurner to manage the RSS of your blog, you can go to the `Publicize` tab, then click on the `Socialize` sidebar link and set-up FeedBurner to post on Twitter when a new post comes up (it has more options then FriendFeed).

Comment: I did not know about the FeedBurner thing. Great solution! Took all of 5 seconds to get it working. Thanks!

Comment: @Drew glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Feedburner for your RSS, you can do it directly from the "Publicize" tab under "Socialize". Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

I think [twitterfeed](http://www.twitterfeed.com/) would be better idea, you give your blog rss+twitter account to twitterfeed and set monitor schedule, twitterfeed will send your scheduled post after publish.

Answer (score 0):

Best Twitter Plugin for Wordpress (and I tried around 10 or so) seems to be "WP to Twitter" http://www.joedolson.com/articles/wp-to-twitter/

It seems to be the only one where you can define a CUSTOM text to tweet. I hate tweeting just the headlines - seems stupid to me because that is what the RSS feed already is made for.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use IFTTT to social integration and update from all forms https://ifttt.com/

Comment: Hey, I suggest giving a more thorough explanation of how to use this service to accomplish the task.