# Can I modify the format of the text used to post to Twitter by Typepad?

Tags: twitter, typepad, tweet

I dislike the format that Typepad uses when posting to Twitter to alert my followers that I've created a new blog post. Is there a mechanism to change the format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I answered in the question ["Is there a Wordpress plugin that will tweet when a scheduled post is posted?"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2840/is-there-a-wordpress-plugin-that-will-tweet-when-a-scheduled-post-is-posted/2850#2850), if you use **FeedBurner** to manage your blog's RSS feed, you can set it up to post to Twitter automatically. It even offers a bunch of options about the format of the tweet.

> If you use FeedBurner to manage the RSS of your blog, you can go to the Publicize  tab, then click on the Socialize sidebar link and set-up FeedBurner to post on Twitter when a new post comes up (it has more options then FriendFeed).

Answer (score 1):

First, turn off the Twitter alert option in Typepad, then go sign up for [dlvr.it](http://dlvr.it/) or [twitterfeed](http://twitterfeed.com/).  Then enter the URL for your Typepad's RSS feed and customize to your heart's content!